# How to update the work buffer if nothing is in it

Tags: linux, vim

IN VIM--I need to update the work buffer with 100 lines of 50 c's on each line. The work buffer is currently empty. Can someone please point me in the right direction?? maybe a web site or a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick 'n Dirty... `50ic` `<ESC>` `dd100P`

Or, use a macro.

`qq50ic` `<ESC>` `o` `<ESC>` `q100@q`

`qq` starts recording a macro in the `q` register.

`50` to repeat the next command 50 times.

`ic<ESC>` insert 1 c (50 times)

`o<ESC>`  insert a newline and return to normal mode

`q` stop recording the macro

`100@q` run the `q` macro 100 times.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in editor?? I tried that with a few other variations and no success.

Comment: @jake .. What do you mean, "in editor"? Starting in normal mode with the buffer active, the commands in my answer create your wall of cs...

Comment: I just wanted to thank you this is the way I was looking for beginner mistake. I typed it in and it worked. I wasn't looking for a script it turns out.

Comment: Achievement unlocked: homework solving automation. :)

Comment: @lcd047.. What kind of homework would this be?  Honest question, I've never run across vi-specifice homework..

Comment: @oobivat The OP admitted (in a comment now deleted) it was homework.  Perhaps ask the OP?

Comment: @lcd047.. Ah, I didn't see that. What kind of homework was this for, @jake? Just curious where you're learning vim..